# When i'm checking for integer, when it is not a int function outputs Error, why?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def check_isbn13(a):
    if type(a)== int: # check for int
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Checked for an int, but when it is not an int, function outputs an error

Comment: And the exact, complete text of this error somehow didn't seem like an important detail to mention?

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the input and the full error traceback message. You can [edit] the question. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) if you want more tips.